# How to load a library from Module using codeigniter modular extensions

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

**i need to load a library from my module using Modular Extensions**

**my structure like this**

modules/

modules/categories/library

- categories_class.php

modules/categories/controllers/

- categories.php

  **I need to load categories library in categories controller .**

any one cane help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two problems..

### Problem 1

According to your question, your categories module is not organized properly. The whole purpose of HMVC is compartmentalizing of code e.x; modules. Given your present question how does that structure allow you to copy your modules folder and paste it into another app? **Answer: It doesnt.**.

Follow the example below

It should be the following from the app root:

```
/application/
   config
   modules/
    categories/
      views
      controllers/
        categories.php
      libraries/
        categories_class.php
      models
   libraries
   core
   controllers
```

### Problem 2

per the user guide: https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

You must prefix the module name in front of anything referenced inside the modules folder.

**e.g:** `$this->load->library('module/library');`

**or in your case:** `$this->load->library('categories/categories_class');`

I have attempted previously to exclude the modules folder name and have never gotten it to work.

> Controllers can be loaded as class variables of other controllers
>   using `$this->load->module(’module/controller’);` or simply
>   `$this->load->module(’module’);` if the controller name matches the
>   module name.
>
> Any loaded module controller can then be used like a library, ie:
>   `$this->controller->method()`, but it has access to its own models and
>   libraries independently from the caller.

Comment: i'm sory : i modefied my correct structure .. like you and using   `$this->load->library('categories_class');` but this doesn't work.

Comment: how is that what i said to do.. `$this->load->library('categories/categories_class');`

Comment: My mistake was in the libraries folder. I modify the name to **libraries** instead of  **library** .... thanks Mike for Your Great help.

Answer (score 0):

I have another perspective for this error behavior, that make me spend about 3 hours, actually I am always using combination of Uppercase and Lowercase on my custom libraries on Codeigniter.

For wiredesigz of Codeigniter HMVC, remember the libraries loader behavior as same as CI itself, ***always use lowercase*** of your library classes name instead of actual class name (Maybe combination of uppercase and lowercase)